# The buttons / labels added to the UIScrollView are appeared only on the first page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView paging option enabled with the next code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
        [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        itemName.text = @"Samara";
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
        [subview release];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 6, 1.0);
}
```

I have a number of elements (buttons, labels), added in storyboard to this ScrollView element, but in UI they're appeared only on the first page - the next pages are blank. How can I solve this?

Comment: Something odd is going on in your code. You create a UIView called subview with the size of the UIScrollView and then next you set the text on itemName (ivar ?) what I guess is a UILabel and then add the empty UIView to the UIScrollView?

Comment: @mbogh I just copied this.. and try to understand, how it works. Any ideas how to attach the UILabels to the subViews?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reading through your code example - here is how to make your scrollview page, what you add inside those scrollview is up to you:

```
//Set your scrollView frame
[self.scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460];

//Will use this value to set the content width after the loop
CGFloat scrollWidth = 0;
CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
CGFloat pageHeight = self.scrollView.frame.size.height;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    //Create the page and make the origin.x i * pageWidth
    UIView *page = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i * pageWidth),0,pageWidth,pageHeight)];
    scrollWidth += page.width;
    //Add the page
    [self.scrollView addSubview:page];
}
//set the content size to the right edge of the last page (scrollWidth)
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,pageHeight)];
//Scroll to the last page - assuming you wanted this by looking at the code in your loop
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake((scrollWidth - pageWidth),0,pageWidth,pageHeight)];
//Enable paging and scrolling (scrollEnabled should be YES by default)
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Best I can do based on your code - hope it helps